# how to catch JSON data in php to send it to my email

Tags: javascript, php, json, email, contact-form

I have a contact form that takes data but I am not well versed in this and cannot figure out how to get it linked to my php or how to link the php to an email.

I cannot seem to find which variable links to the php and where to put the php code itself.

This is called when the form is completed:

```
var onComplete = function() {


    // send data to php back end

    transmitJSON('post', "",  questions, function(error, data, meta) {
        console.log("php says:\n\n ",data)
        });

};
```

```
function transmitJSON(method, url, toSend, callback) {
  var callback = callback || function() {}

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhr.open(method, url)
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json')

  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (this.status != 200) return callback({ status: this.status, statusText: xhr.statusText }, null, xhr)
      else {

      try {
        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
      } catch (e) {
        return callback({ status: 202 }, xhr.responseText, xhr)
      }

      return callback(null, json, xhr)

    }
  }

  xhr.onerror = function() {
    return callback({ status: this.status, statusText: xhr.statusText }, null, xhr)
  }

  if (!toSend) xhr.send()
  else {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(toSend))
  }

};
```

than I just have this loose PHP Code and don't know where to put it...:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

echo "php server here :)\n";

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$values = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($values as $question) {
        echo "----------------------\n\n";
        echo $question['question'] . "\n";
        echo $question['answer'] . "\n\n";  
} 

echo "end of message";
exit(0);

}
```

I want the data that I have in json to be caught by the php code and have that send to a specific email.

Answer (score 0):

Send simple without json:

```
$.post('path.php, {name: Var1, email: Var2}, function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

In php:

```
$v1 = $_POST['name'];
$v2 = $_POST['email'];
```

Or read how to send form simple sample FormData() in javascript

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData

And function:

https://github.com/breakermind/XMLHttpRequest